# Napthalene - Friedel Crafts Alkylation and Acylation

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, aromatic-compounds, hydrocarbons

Where does *Friedel Crafts Alkylation and Acylation occur in Napthalene*? Are the reactions kinetic-thermodynamic controlled?

Here's something I came across -

[image]

While alkylation occurs at alpha position, acylation occurs at beta position. Why is it so? Are the other possible minor products also formed? Does *kinetic-thermodynamic control* operate here?

Although I'm worried about Friedel Crafts Alkylation and Acylation reactions at the moment, my question isn't specific to them. In general, given an electrophile for **EAS with Napthalene**, how do we decide which product is major? (The one formed by attack at **alpha**, or **beta** position?)

References would be of great help too.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/10736/nitration-of-naphthalene-and-anthracene https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/28754/naproxene-syntheses-electrophilic-aromatic-substitution-on-activated-naphthalen https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/10736/nitration-of-naphthalene-and-anthracene